# RelativeLayout dosen't get OnClick Events because of the DrawerLayout

Tags: java, android

If I set the order as seen in the picture --> [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amyYz.png)

The DrawerLayout is drawn under the content_main 
And the DrawerLayout dosen't get OnClickEvents

If I set The Order: first content_main then drawer_layout

The DrawerLayout is drawn over the content_main but the content_main doesn't get OnClick Events

Here my activity_main.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />


    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:clickable="true">
        <!--The main content view-->
        <!--The navigation drawer-->
        <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:visibility="visible"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:id="@+id/content_main"
        android:focusable="false">

    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

The Problem is only one of the layouts get OnClickEvents.
How do i do that both Layouts get OnClickEvents.

Sorry for my English.

Comment: @AbdulAhad On the contrary, this is a `RelativeLayout` so the latter-added view - `content_main` in the above code- is the one that appears on the top, and consequently consumes the `onClick` event.

Comment: Please explain how you want the clicks to behave. If you want both layouts to have the same `onClick`, give them the same `OnClickListener`.

Comment: After I was distracted. I found the solution. I took the content_main Layout and put it into the DrawerLayout. Thank you for the efforts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put the content_main into the DrawerLayout as seen in the picture.

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqYe6.png)

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across something for placeholderview onClick. You have to keep the XML file in the correct layout as well else the onClick on the items wont work.

For example in my faulty layout I had
DrawerLayout ->
FrameLayout (for the side menu) ->
LinearLayout (including my UI).

The correct layout was DrawerLayout then LinearLayout and FrameLayout.

I spent a lot of time on a silly mistake. If anyone knows why that would be the case please reply back. Thank you.